# Create multi-factor geom_bar with distributions assoicated with each other

Tags: r, ggplot2

Take the following sample data:

```
set.seed(123456)
#
Male_alive <- rbinom(100,1,0.6)
Male_age <- sample(20:80, 100, T)
#
Female_alive <- rbinom(100,1,0.7)
Female_age <- sample(20:80, 100, T)
#
Alive <- c(Male_alive, Female_alive)
Age <- c(Male_age, Female_age)
Sex <- c(rep('Male', length(Male_alive)),rep('Female', length(Female_alive)))
#
Patients <- data.frame(Alive, Age, Sex)
```

I can create a simple bar plot with the following code:

```
ggplot(Patients, aes(Sex, fill = factor(Alive))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

But I want to extend on this, by creating a multi-factored bar plot (for Sex and AgeGr) that looks like the image (colours are not important):

[image]

```
#
Patients$AgeGr <- cut(Patients$Age, 6)
```

using

```
ggplot(Patients, aes(..., fill = factor(Alive))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") + geom_wrap(~Sex)
```

Where the `AgeGr` is only *fills* up to the corresponding height of `Alive`

Comment: I think you'll find this approach helpful: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmosaic/vignettes/ggmosaic.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this could be a terrible way to do it:

```
#to get plots side by side
library(gridExtra)

#plot count of males
pmales <-ggplot(Patients[Patients$Sex=='Male',], aes(Sex, fill =factor(Alive))) + geom_bar(position='fill')

#plot grage males0
pagegrmales0 <-ggplot(Patients[Patients$Sex=='Male' & Patients$Alive==0,], aes(Sex, fill =factor(AgeGr))) + geom_bar(position='fill') + ylab(NULL) +xlab(NULL) + theme(legend.position="none", plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,-0.5,1), "cm"))

#plot grage males1
pagegrmales1 <-ggplot(Patients[Patients$Sex=='Male' & Patients$Alive==1,], aes(Sex, fill =factor(AgeGr))) + geom_bar(position='fill') + ylab(NULL) +xlab(NULL) + theme(legend.position="none", plot.margin=unit(c(-0.5,1,1,1), "cm"))

factorsmale <- grid.arrange(pagegrmales0, pagegrmales1, heights=c(prop.table(table(Patients[Patients$Sex=='Male',]$Alive))[[1]], prop.table(table(Patients[Patients$Sex=='Male',]$Alive))[[2]]), nrow=2)

males <- grid.arrange(pmales, factorsmale, ncol =2, nrow= 2)

########

#plot count of females
pfemales <-ggplot(Patients[Patients$Sex=='Female',], aes(Sex, fill =factor(Alive))) + geom_bar(position='fill')

#plot grage females0
pagegrfemales0 <-ggplot(Patients[Patients$Sex=='Female' & Patients$Alive==0,], aes(Sex, fill =factor(AgeGr))) + geom_bar(position='fill') + ylab(NULL) +xlab(NULL) + theme(legend.position="none", plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,-0.5,1), "cm"))

#plot grage females1
pagegrfemales1 <-ggplot(Patients[Patients$Sex=='Female' & Patients$Alive==1,], aes(Sex, fill =factor(AgeGr))) + geom_bar(position='fill') + ylab(NULL) +xlab(NULL) + theme(legend.position="none", plot.margin=unit(c(-0.5,1,1,1), "cm"))

factorsfemale <- grid.arrange(pagegrfemales0, pagegrfemales1, heights=c(prop.table(table(Patients[Patients$Sex=='Female',]$Alive))[[1]], prop.table(table(Patients[Patients$Sex=='Female',]$Alive))[[2]]), nrow=2)

females <- grid.arrange(pfemales, factorsfemale, ncol =2, nrow= 2)

grid.arrange(males, females, ncol = 2, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Combine the alive and agegroup columns

```
Patients$Alive_AgeGr <- paste(Patients$Alive, Patients$AgeGr, sep="_")
```

Plot

```
ggplot(Patients, aes(x = factor(Alive), fill = factor(AgeGr))) +
    geom_bar(position = "fill") + facet_wrap(~Sex)
```

[image: plot of alive and age group]

Comment: I believe this is not the behavior OP is looking for

Comment: @erasmortg, I see the plot in your answer is different. The OP really wants to reproduce the plot he gave in the question. I had not understood that AgeGrp was divided by Alive in the original plot.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create long format dataset with only required columns and then plot the stacked-bar plot with wrap, as below:

```
library("reshape2")
mPatients <- melt(Patients[,-2], id.vars = "Sex")

ggplot(mPatients, aes(x=variable, fill = factor(value))) +
    geom_bar(position = "fill") + facet_wrap(~Sex)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but the AgeGr should be repeated twice within each facet. Once for Alive==1 and then again for Alive==0. That said, the first set of Male-AgeGr should only rise up to about 0.7

Comment: Was that in the requirement of the question? If it is not, please edit or ask a new question.

Comment: When looking at the image of the desired out --- for Male -- Alive -- the green section contributes about 50% and the red %. Then within each of these 50% sections, the distribution of AgeGr is plotted for each